# Can you recommend an interesting driver application that's fit for novice?

Tags: c++, c, windows, driver

I'm totally new to driver development,

seeking of an interesting driver related task to get started.

Comment: why have you tagged this message with C++ :P

Comment: I suppose C++ can also be used to write drivers,wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that only C is used for driver development

Comment: Wow,that's the best,I like c more than c++:)

Comment: C++ can be used to write Windows drivers, but it requires that you understand how the compiler works. You'll have to know that MSVC generates vtables, for instance, and non-pageable requirements apply even when making a virtual call.

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of series of articles on [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/driverdev.aspx). You can start by looking these articles.

Comment: You can look at my article too: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/fs-filter-driver-tutorial.aspx :)

Answer (score 2):

There was a question here with an idea which I liked, as a cool driver idea.

Make a keyboard filter driver that would let an application retrieve the exact precise timing of keystrokes (QueryPerformanceCounter) which would enable reaction speed tests and such.

There may be other applications, such as spelling correctios based on key timing. Imagine msword's teh->the but only when E and H keystrokes are very near on the time axis.